# Getting multiple browser details in User-Agent

Tags: spring-boot, user-agent

I need to take browser details of an API which is requested by a client , By using user-agent i am able to take all details but it contains multiple browsers. So which one should i take, and spring boot is the frame work which i am using.

Controller code

```
    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "heartbeatservice",produces="application/json")
    public String heartBeatService(Model modelAtrrubute,@RequestHeader("User-Agent") String userAgent) {

 System.out.println("---------------"+userAgent);


}
```

Out Put

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score -1):

When you make a request from `Rest-Client` u can set `header` as you want. Like `User-Agent` : `Android`. Browser default behavior they pass their `User-Agent`.

Above information is correct. Look at this [User-Agent-History](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

1. `Firefox` : `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0`

   - Contains `Firefox/32.0` - it should be `Firefox 32.0`
2. `Chrome` : `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36`

   - Contains `'Chrome'`, but not `'Chromium'` - so it would appear to be Chrome version `68.0`

Comment: But, how can i figure out from which browser api is requesting ?. We got list of browsers in User-Agent.

Comment: Contains Firefox/32.0 - it should be Firefox 32.0

Comment: but actually i called this api from Chrome. And user agent contails Mozilla,Chrome and Safari all these things...

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/85.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/85.5

Comment: safari contains this. here is no chrome